# Reloading dynamically generated page results in going back to first page, in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am generating pages dynamically in a jquery mobile app. They show. The problem is that if the user hits the reload button on a dynamically generated page the will go back to the first page.

Here is the example. Save the following file as t.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>JQM latest - issue template</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/git/jquery.mobile-git.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/git/jquery.mobile-git.js"></script>
  <script>$(document).ready(function(){
    var newPage = '<div data-role="page" id="dynamic"><div data-role="header"><h1>Dynamic Page</h1></div><div class="ui-content"><ul><li>This page is dynamically generated.</li></ul></div></div>';
    $.mobile.pageContainer.append(newPage);
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

  <div data-role="page" id="homepage">
    <div data-role="header">
      <h1>Issue template</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->
    <div class="ui-content">
      <ul>
        <li>We are on the Homepage</li>
        <li>Go to <a href="#static">static</a></li>
        <li>Go to <a href="#dynamic">dynamic</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /content -->
  </div><!-- /page -->

  <div data-role="page" id="static">
    <div data-role="header">
      <h1>Static Page</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->
    <div class="ui-content">
      <ul>
        <li>This page is in the index.html.</li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /content -->
  </div><!-- /page -->

</body>
</html>
```

Then

1. Load t.html in the browser
2. click on 'static', the URL will now be t.html#static and you will see that page
3. Reload the page (click on the browser's reload page button), you will still see #static
4. Go back to t.html
5. Click on 'dynamic', the URL will now be t.html#dynamic and you will see that page
6. Reload the page (browser reload button), you are now back at the homepage index.html, but the URL still shows t.html#dynamic

How can I make it so that when the user reloads (step 6) the dynamic page we stay at that page?

Comment: have you tried JQM changePage options `reloadPage` and `allowSamePageTransition`? Info [here](http://api.jquerymobile.com/jQuery.mobile.changePage/)

Comment: I don't know what you mean. I am not calling changePage() anywhere in the code above. The problem is when the user hits the browser's reload button.

Comment: do you get a 404 or error on Firebug on step 6?

Comment: Nope, no errors appear on firebug or chrome dev tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guided by ezanker's response, I went to the docs to see if there was a way to postpone when the whole page is being created. There is, it is by setting `mobile.autoInitializePage` to false and then calling `initializePage()` when needed. That is what my solution below does.

This way, there is no arbitrary timeout. The dynamic page is the only one that shows when I click on the reload button.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>JQM latest - issue template</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/git/jquery.mobile-git.css">

  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script>
   $(document).bind("mobileinit", function () {
      console.log('mobileinit called');
     $.mobile.autoInitializePage = false;
    });
</script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/git/jquery.mobile-git.js"></script>
  <script>$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log('document ready');
    var newPage = $('<div data-role="page" id="dynamic" data-url="yay"><div data-role="header"><h1>Dynamic Page</h1></div><div class="ui-content"><ul><li>This page is dynamically generated.</li></ul></div></div>');
    newPage.appendTo($('body'));
    $.mobile.initializePage();
});
</script>

</head>
<body>

  <div data-role="page" id="homepage">
    <div data-role="header">
      <h1>Issue template</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->
    <div class="ui-content">
      <ul>
        <li>We are on the Homepage</li>
        <li>Go to <a href="#static">static</a></li>
        <li>Go to <a href="#dynamic">dynamic</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /content -->
  </div><!-- /page -->

  <div data-role="page" id="static">
    <div data-role="header">
      <h1>Static Page</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->
    <div class="ui-content">
      <ul>
        <li>This page is in the index.html.</li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /content -->
  </div><!-- /page -->

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when you reload, the whole page is being created from scratch and the dynamic content does not exist until that script runs.

You can do something like this:

```
$(document).on("pageinit", "#homepage", function(){        
    var newPage = '<div data-role="page" id="dynamic"><div data-role="header"><h1>Dynamic Page</h1></div><div class="ui-content"><ul><li>This page is dynamically generated.</li></ul></div></div>';
    $.mobile.pageContainer.append(newPage);

    if (window.location.hash == "#dynamic"){
        setTimeout(GoToDynamicPage, 50);
    }

});

function GoToDynamicPage(){
    $.mobile.changePage("#dynamic");
}
```

On pageinit, check the URL hash, and if it is the id of the dynamic page, use changePage() to go there.  The user will probably see the home page momentarily before the dynamic page is reloaded.  The setTimeout seems to be needed to let jQM finish its business...

> Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/M5vr5/1/)**

In the fiddle, visit the dynamic page, then right click and reload the frame.

Comment: First page appears for a while, use pagebeforechange to go to dynamic page.

Comment: Ok, yes, that worked. It does show the original page for those 50ms. I wish we did not have that magic 50 there, especially since this is for a mobile app so I'm expecting slow connections and slow phones, so the 50ms would probably have to be increased. Maybe someone else can come up with a better answer? If not, I'll mark this one as the answer.

Comment: Omar: how would I use the pagebeforechange event?

Comment: @Omar, feel free to update my fiddle using pagebeforechange, i could not figure out what you mean as the dynamic content has to get created before you can navigate to it....